# Bytebuddy Advice is not always working in Java agent

Tags: byte-buddy

I have a simple bytebuddy agent which records method entry/exit. I run it as

```sh
export MAVEN_OPTS="-javaagent:$JAVA_AGENT=$CONFIG_FILE"
mvn clean test -DargLine="-javaagent:$JAVA_AGENT_JAR"
```

It works well for couple of my Java projects. However, when I tried it on few open source projects: [flink](https://github.com/apache/flink), [guava](https://github.com/google/guava), [dubbo](https://github.com/apache/dubbo) it dint work.

- JDK: 1.8
- ByteBuddy: 1.10.18

Here is code snippet

```java
  @Override
  public void instrument(Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    final Advice methodAdvice = Advice.to(MethodTracer.class);
    ElementMatcher.Junction matcher = nameStartsWithAnyOf(includes);

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .with(new TracerLogger())
            .type(matcher)
            .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> {
                builder = builder.visit(new AsmVisitorWrapper.ForDeclaredMethods().method(ElementMatchers.isMethod(), methodAdvice));
                System.out.println("transform() called");
                return builder;
              }
            })
            .installOn(instrumentation);
  }
```

```java
public class MethodTracer {
  @Advice.OnMethodEnter(inline = false)
  public static StackNode enter(
      @Advice.Origin("#t") String type, @Advice.Origin("#m") String method, @Advice.Origin("#s") String signature) {
    System.out.println("OnMethodEnter() called");
    return CallableTracer.enter(type, method, signature, false);
  }

  @Advice.OnMethodExit(inline = false, onThrowable = Throwable.class)
  public static void exit(@Advice.Enter StackNode node) {
    CallableTracer.exit(node);
  }
```

When I run, it prints `transform() called`

but it never prints `OnMethodEnter() called`
any hint to resolve this? Thanks

---

**Update:** To answer Rafael's questions: Yes, tracer logger outputs. Some samples are here:

```
[2020-12-28 08:22:40:292] [DEBUG] [TracerLogger] onTransformation: class org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.AbstractRichFunction, null, false, agent.rt.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded@7e56d17f
[2020-12-28 08:22:40:292] [DEBUG] [TracerLogger] onComplete: org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.AbstractRichFunction, null, false
```

I don't see any log from `onError()`, so not sure if its transformation error.

adding these to pom.xml allowed me to register retransformation strategy, but the Advice is still not working.

```xml
<Can-Redefine-Classes>true</Can-Redefine-Classes>
<Can-Retransform-Classes>true</Can-Retransform-Classes>
```

This is how I register retransformation strategy:

```java
.with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
.with(AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.NoOp.INSTANCE)
.with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE)
```

I ran with `.with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemOut())`. for flink methods, it prints `loaded=false`

Comment: Does your trace logger output anything? It's likely a transformation error. Maybe the classes are already loaded? Try registering a retransformation strategy.

Comment: @coder99, please do not post code and logs inline in a comment like you did, it is totally unreadable. I took the liberty to move your comments into the question and format them for you this time, so you can actually delete the comments now.

Comment: This seems alright, might the code be running in an endless loop? If old code is executing, it is not retransformed until after the loop is released.